# Problem with understanding solution of discrete mathematics task

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> The task says: three dice are thrown. On how many ways sum of numbers the dice will be 14?

This a solution:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f3qo.jpg

I understand first two rows, but I don't understand how did we go from second to third row, how did  $\sum_{n=0}^∞ $ $\ {-3} \choose {n}$ $ (-x^n) $ became $\sum_{n=0}^∞ $ $\ {n+2} \choose {2} $ $ x^n$ ?

Also, how did go from third to forth row ?

Any help is appricated.

Comment: it's important to note that that it's $(-x)^n$ which changes sign based on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [negative binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html) says that $(x + 1)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{k}x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. Substituting in the values from your two series shows the equality. More specifically we have:

\begin{align*} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{k}(-x)^k &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{3 + k - 1}{k}(-(-x))^k\\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}{k}x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k}{2}x^k\end{align*}

where the last equality comes from the symmetry rule for binomial coefficients. The last line of your picture is extracting the $14$th coefficient from the generating function $f$ since we want the sum of the dice to add to $14$.